# Can't call startRecordingToOutputFileURL more than once on instance of AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I am currently testing on iOS 8, on an iPhone 6. I am calling these APIs from Swift.

I'm trying to figure out why I can't call `startRecordingToOutputFileURL` more than once on a single instance of `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`.

- I am calling `stopRecording` before I call `startRecordingToOutputFileURL` again.
- I am deleting the temporary video file before calling `startRecordingToOutputFileURL`.

The first time that I call `startRecordingToOutputFileURL`, the `didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL` delegate callback is fired. When I call `stopRecording`, the `didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL` callback is fired.

After this, I delete the temporary file.

Then, when I call `startRecordingToOutputFileURL` the next time, the delegate callback is not fired. And when I call `stopRecording` a second time, the "finished" callback is not fired either.

The [Apple docs for 
startRecordingToOutputFileURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutput_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureFileOutput/startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:) say the following:

> In iOS, this frame accurate file switching is not supported. You must call stopRecording before calling this method again to avoid any errors.

However, I am calling `stopRecording` before calling it again, and it is not working.

My current workaround is to remove the `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` connection, initialize a new instance of `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, and then set up a new connection. This is terrible, because it takes a long time and freezes the video preview.

Please let me know if you know why this is happening, and if there is a fix.

**UPDATE**: I just noticed that if I toggle my `AVCaptureSession` `sessionPreset` to `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` and then back to `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`, then I can start capturing video again.

**UPDATE 2**: Here's another way I can fix the problem:

```
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    captureSession.startRunning()
```

**UPDATE 3**: It turns out that this seems to be related to some code that captures the volume buttons - [JPSVolumeButtonHandler](https://github.com/jpsim/JPSVolumeButtonHandler). It doesn't happen when I comment out the code that starts `JPSVolumeButtonHandler`.